# Repeating section : SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

[image]

I need to fetch data from SP list using Client object model with JQuery, that queries a list and binds data to the Table in a looping format as shown in the pic below. The table has different types of controls and third party jquery controls. Can this be accomplished with simple Jquery CSOM? Please suggest.